# Show interactive offline plot generated from plotly in powerpoint slides

Tags: powerpoint, plotly

I generated an offline interactive plot with plotly.

I save the plot as html file. Does anyone know I can embed the interactive plot to MS powerpoint for presentation?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint does not natively support html features, however there are some plugins available for that purpose, like [iSpring](https://www.ispringsolutions.com/blog/how-to-embed-an-iframe-in-a-powerpoint-presentation/).

Comment: Thank you so much!  iSpring seem to have 2-week free trial. do not know what is going to happen after that. Is there any other free plugins that also serve the purpose? @vlizana

Comment: I've seen some free options out there but most of them are outdated, personally when I have to present using plotly I use Jupyter notebooks' [slides](https://medium.com/@mjspeck/presenting-code-using-jupyter-notebook-slides-a8a3c3b59d67).

Answer (score 0):

There is plotly d3.js add-in to powerpoint

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104379485?tab=Overview

But seems you need to upload your files to plotly account. I haven't figured out how to embed local files